# Как найти причину неработающего слайдера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Из шаблона скопировал код слайдера на `jquery` на другой сайт. Подключена библиотека 1.12.0 плюс подключил скрипт с названием "slider" думал в нём дело. Выдаёт ошибку и слайдер не работает. [image: Изображение]

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#banner-slider-demo-14").owlCarousel({autoPlay:true,lazyLoad:true,stopOnHover: true,pagination: false, autoPlay: true,navigation: true,navigationText:["<i class='icon-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='icon-chevron-right'></i>"],slideSpeed : 500,paginationSpeed : 500,singleItem:true,transitionStyle:"fade"});
    });
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Скорее всего не подключен плагин owlCarousel или он вызывается выше чем подключен.

Comment: Имеется ввиду js? Я так понимаю для прямого вывода сладйера, достаточно написать html разметку и там же написать сценарий на jquery.

Comment: Да, `owl.carousel.min.js` или `owl.carousel.js`

Comment: Благодарю!!! Его не хватало.

Comment: Оформил ответ ниже!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не подключен плагин карусели `owl.carousel.min.js` и когда вы вызываете его, jQuery не может найти данную функцию.